# How do I simply move a Silverlight Rectangle programmatically? There is no simple x/y to use

Tags: silverlight

How to move a Silverlight Rectangle?

I want to say rect1.X++ to move a rectangle as a timer event is activated... It's easy to change the height like rect1.Height++;

Is there some easy way to do this without having to deal with complex matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a TranslateTransform to move an element:

```
<Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Red">
     <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
          <TranslateTransform x:Name="myTranslateTransform" />
     </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

You can then reference it in code:

```
myTranslateTransform.X = 30;
myTranslateTransform.Y = 100;
```

However, the "correct" way (and also the way you can do other things like animate the translation) would be to set the values for the transform in the VisualStateManager and use `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` instead of manipulating the values in code directly like above.

Answer (score 1):

If it's on a canvas, set the `Canvas.LeftProperty` and `Canvas.TopProperty` values.  Here's a snip from one of my projects, moving a (rectangular) foot:

```
        // at startup:
        _rightFoot = new Rectangle();
        _myCanvas.Children.Add(_rightFoot);

        // during animation cycle:
        _rightFoot.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, _xRight - _footWidth/2);
        _rightFoot.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, _yRight - _footHeight/2);
```

Comment: thanks. seems like a way to do the same thing without the XAML I guess.